# Unable to parse variable into the ForEach ($Server in $Servers) loop?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to correct the below script to query the server logon session using Qwinsta.

The goal of this server is to show who is currently logged on.

The script main section:

> $queryResults = (qwinsta /server:$ServerName | Select-Object -Skip 1 |
> ForEach-Object { (($_.trim() -replace "\s+", ",")) } | convertfrom-csv
> -ErrorAction Stop)

is working fine:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $queryResults

services      0     Disc  
--------      -     ----  
console       1     Conn  
Administrator 3     Disc  
rdp-tcp       65536 Listen
```

Script:

```
$HtmlHead = @"
<style>
    body {
        font-family: Arial;
    }
    table {
        width: 100%;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border: 1px solid;
    }
    th {
        background-color: green;
        border: 1px solid;
        padding: 1px;
    }
    td {
        border: 1px solid;
        padding: 1px;
    }
</style>
"@

$Today = Get-Date -Format 'F'
$SessionList = "`n`nRDP Session List - " + $Today + "`n`n"
$CurrentSN = 0

# Get a list of servers from Active Directory
write-progress -activity "Getting list of servers from Active Directory" -status "... please wait ..."

$Servers = Get-ADComputer -Filter { Enabled -eq $True -and OperatingSystem -like "*Server*" } -SearchBase "OU=Servers,DC=Company,DC=com," | Where-Object { Test-Connection $_.Name -Count 1 -Quiet } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

$NumberOfServers = $Servers.Count

# Iterate through the retrieved list to check RDP sessions on each machine
ForEach ($Server in $Servers) {

    $ServerName = $Server.Name
    Write-Host "Processing $($Server.Name) ..." -ForegroundColor Yellow
    Write-progress -activity "Checking RDP Sessions" -status "Querying $ServerName" -percentcomplete (($CurrentSN / $NumberOfServers) * 100)

    # Run qwinsta and grab the output
    try {
        $queryResults = (qwinsta /server:$ServerName | Select-Object -Skip 1 | ForEach-Object { (($_.trim() -replace "\s+", ",")) } | convertfrom-csv -ErrorAction Stop)

        # get session info from the instance
        ForEach ($QueryResult in $QueryResults) {

            $RDPUser = $($QueryResult.substring(19, 22)).trim()
            $SessionType = $($QueryResult.substring(1, 18)).trim()
            $SessionID = $($QueryResult.substring(41, 5)).trim()
            $ReturnedCurrentState = $($QueryResult.substring(48, 8)).trim()

            $RDPUser = $QueryResult.USERNAME
            $SessionType = $QueryResult.SESSIONNAME
            $SessionID = $QueryResult.ID
            $ReturnedCurrentState = $QueryResult.State

            If ($ReturnedCurrentState -eq $null) { $CurrentState = "Disconnected" } Else { $CurrentState = "Active" }

            # filter out the irrelevant information
            If (($RDPUser -ne $null) -and ($SessionType -ne "console") -and ($SessionType -ne "services") -and ($SessionType -ne "rdp-tcp") -and ($RDPUser -ne "65536")) {
                $SessionList = $SessionList + "`n" + $ServerName + " logged in by " + $RDPUser + " on " + $SessionType + ", session id $SessionID $CurrentState"
            }
        }

    }
    catch {
        $SessionList = $SessionList + "`n Unable to query " + $ServerName
        write-host "Unable to query $ServerName!" -foregroundcolor Red
    }

    $CurrentSN++
}

# Send the output the screen.
$SessionList + "`n`n"

$sendMailArgs = @{
    From       = "$env:USERNAME@$env:userdnsdomain"
    To         = 'SOC@domain.com'
    SmtpServer = 'SMTP.domain.com'
    Priority   = 'High'
    BodyAsHtml = $true
    Body       = ($SessionList | ConvertTo-Html -Head $HtmlHead) -join "`r`n"
    Subject    = "$($SessionList.Count) Logged On users from $($NumberOfServers) online servers as at $($Today)"
}

Send-MailMessage @sendMailArgs
```

The problem is that the script loop is always going into:

> ```
>     write-host "Unable to query $ServerName!" -foregroundcolor Red
> ```

The email result is always like:

```
*
424
```

What is that mean?

Comment: Updated as requested.

Comment: Add [exception handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-7) to see what's the exceptional error message.

Comment: Yes, I have already included the Try/Catch

Comment: Sure, but the catch block doesn't do anything with the exception. See [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38421525/503046) about how to see what the exception actually is about.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the *Substring()* method throws an exception because the startIndex parameter values of 41 and 48 seem large. If *$QueryResult* string ends up shorter, you will get that exception and immediately move to the catch statement.

I would recommend separating error handling for querying the server and building the session list.

UPDATE:
Here's how you can separate error handling in your script example. Basically you need to be aware of methods or cmdlets which can theoretically throw an exception with the input parameters you provide and cover those cases.

```
ForEach ($Server in $Servers) {

    $ServerName = $Server.Name
    Write-Host "Processing $ServerName ..." -ForegroundColor Yellow
    Write-progress -activity "Checking RDP Sessions" -status "Querying $ServerName" -percentcomplete (($CurrentSN / $NumberOfServers) * 100)

    # Run qwinsta and grab the output
    try {
        $queryResults = (qwinsta /server:$ServerName | Select-Object -Skip 1 | ForEach-Object { (($_.trim() -replace "\s+", ",")) } | convertfrom-csv )
    }
    catch {
        # Error handling for failed server connection here
        $SessionList += "`n Unable to query " + $ServerName
        write-host "Unable to query $ServerName!" -foregroundcolor Red
        continue # Skip to next $Server
    }
    # get session info from the instance
    ForEach ($QueryResult in $QueryResults) {
        try {
            # Do something about this
            $RDPUser = $($QueryResult.substring(19, 22)).trim()
            $SessionType = $($QueryResult.substring(1, 18)).trim()
            $SessionID = $($QueryResult.substring(41, 5)).trim()
            $ReturnedCurrentState = $($QueryResult.substring(48, 8)).trim()
    
            $RDPUser = $QueryResult.USERNAME
            $SessionType = $QueryResult.SESSIONNAME
            $SessionID = $QueryResult.ID
            $ReturnedCurrentState = $QueryResult.State
        }
        catch {
            # Insert your error handling here
            # Write-Host "Failed to process query result from $ServerName!" -foregroundcolor Red
             
            Write-Host $Error[0].Exception # If you want to get the exception message. A shorter way to do it below
            # Write-Host $_
        }

        If ($null -eq $ReturnedCurrentState) { $CurrentState = "Disconnected" } Else { $CurrentState = "Active" }

        # filter out the irrelevant information
        If (($null -ne $RDPUser) -and ($SessionType -ne "console") -and ($SessionType -ne "services") -and ($SessionType -ne "rdp-tcp") -and ($RDPUser -ne "65536")) {
            $SessionList = $SessionList + "`n" + $ServerName + " logged in by " + $RDPUser + " on " + $SessionType + ", session id $SessionID $CurrentState"
        }
    }
    $CurrentSN++
}
```

I am genuinely concerned about the code block where you assign values to variables like `$RDPUser`, `$SessionType`, etc. I'll give you the benefit of the doubt that I don't know your environment, but the logic looks very strange. If `$QueryResult` is an object with several properties, why substring? The object doesn't have this method. If it's just a long string with values at certain character positions, why try to get its property values like `$QueryResult.ID` - it doesn't have any.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, would you be able to show me how to do it on multiple Try/Catch nested?

Comment: Sure, I've updated my original answer with an example.

Comment: that is great, many thank you for the detailed explanations and sharing of the thought process, it helps me on this question.