Azure Devops build pipeline does not have detailed error message after API call to Power BI
I'm developing Azure Devops build pipeline which will automate Power Bi deployments using Power BI deployment pipelines. Yaml file is executing my powershell script which contains all the logic and and the end it is running a command:
try{
    $deployResult = Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url $url  -Method Post -Body $body | ConvertFrom-Json
}
catch {
    $errorMsg = Resolve-PowerBIError -Last
    Write-Output $errorMsg.Message
}

The command is working fine both locally and in a pipeline, but the problem is when sometime there is an error during deployment (typically user error) the output in pipeline is only consists of 1 line which makes it hard to debug those issues.
Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).
But, locally, exactly same script returns me much more info:
{
  "code": "Alm_InvalidRequest_ArtifactsValidationFailure",
  "pbi.error": {
    "code": "Alm_InvalidRequest_ArtifactsValidationFailure",
    "details": [
      {
        "code": "Alm_InvalidRequest_ArtifactReferenceModelWithoutPermissions",
        "detail": {
          "type": 1,
          "value": "{\"artifactTypeName\":\"Reports\",\"artifactId\":\"xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx\"}"
        }
      }
    ],
    "exceptionCulprit": 1
  }
}

Yaml file is:
---
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - INT
variables:
  workspaceName: My workspace [Development]
  pipelineName: My pipeline
stages:
  - stage: DeployToINT
    jobs:
    - deployment: DeployToINT
      pool:
        name: POWERBI
      environment: Power BI test
      strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:
            - task: CmdLine@2
              inputs:
                script: 'git config --system core.longpaths true'
            - checkout: git://Power BI/_git/DevOps@test
            - checkout: self
              fetchDepth: 100
            - task: PowerShell@2
              inputs:
                filePath: './DevOps/testApicall.ps1'
                arguments: '-passwordKey "$(passwordKeyINT)"'
                failOnStderr: true
                showWarnings: true

PowerShell script which I'm using. Sensitive data substituted with <>:
param(
    $passwordKey = "<password>"
)
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
$reportsList = @()

[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
Write-Output  "Logging into Power BI Service..."

$serviceAccnt_User = "<username>"
[securestring]$secStringPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $passwordKey -AsPlainText -Force
[pscredential]$PBILogin_Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($serviceAccnt_User, $secStringPassword)
$null = Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount -Credential $PBILogin_Cred -ErrorAction Stop
$reportsList += @{sourceId = "<ArtifactID>" }
$url = "pipelines/<pipelineID>/Deploy"
$body = @{ 
            sourceStageOrder = 0      

            reports = @(
                $reportsList
            )       

            options = @{
                # Allows creating new artifact
                allowCreateArtifact = $TRUE

                # Allows overwriting existing artifact
                allowOverwriteArtifact = $TRUE

                allowPurgeData = $TRUE

                allowTakeOver = $TRUE       
            }

            updateAppSettings = @{
                updateAppInTargetWorkspace = $false
            }
               
        } | ConvertTo-Json

try{
    $deployResult = Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url $url  -Method Post -Body $body | ConvertFrom-Json
}
catch {
    $errMsg = Resolve-PowerBIError -Last
    Write-Output $errMsg.message
}

I tried to work with exit codes and error handling, but whatever I tried, still produces same output.
Is there a way how to fix this issue in Azure Devops pipeline?

Try outputting more exception details, as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38419325/catching-full-exception-message


Set up a self-hosted agent on your local machine and then run the pipeline using it to check whether you can see the same error. 2. Whether you can see the detailed error after enabling verbose log? 3. Please share the completed YAML file of your Azure pipeine.


@RuiJarimba, I tried to, but this didn't helped. Locally it contains System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException with message, that I need, but in pipeline it is just
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).

@ZiyangLiu-MSFT

Unfortunately I can't do that because this is handled by separate ops team which will not let me do that.
No, this does not have more info about this request error
Yaml file is very simple. It just have checkout code and then run script. I updated original message with yaml file


Hi @Aleksandrs Petrovs, can you share an easy PowerShell script that can reproduce 400 error with us? I haven't been able to reproduce the same issue from my side. Ensure to remove personal info from the script.

@ZiyangLiu-MSFT Updated initial message with PowerShell script

@ZiyangLiu-MSFT Actually I had a permission to access self hosted agent which runs this pipeline and executed my script. It is producing same error as in pipeline (no details). Seems like the difference are in between those two machines. Do you have an idea what could cause this?

According to your description, the issue is related to the agent used by you. You can try to install and import the latest MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt on your affected agent and check what's the result. Refer to my answer below.

you can use Powershell transcript and log in different file or even use instead of file path in yaml script inline and write the script to start-transcript and call the Powershell file then end transcript and show the output
for more details check this :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.host/start-transcript?view=powershell-7.4

I have tested in my pipeline referring to your PowerShell scripts. I can see the detailed error message in the pipeline log. For example,

According to your update, "I had a permission to access self hosted agent which runs this pipeline and executed my script. It is producing same error as in pipeline (no details)", the issue is related to the specific agent. You can try to install and import the latest MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt on your affected agent and check what's the result.
Install-Module -Name MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt -Scope CurrentUser -Force -AllowClobber
Import-Module MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt

The version of my PowerShell: 5.1.
